# Uploading pdf file in laravel vuejs Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have created a project for bookshop and in the section of employee information I want to upload a PDF file using code given below.it give me the below error.I have been trying since few days but I could not get the solution if there is any sample way please guide me
any help will be highly appreciated

> **The given data was invalid.","errors":{"file":["The file field is
>   required.**

**controller code is**

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
       $DocumentType= new DocumentType();
                  $this->validate($request,[
            'name'=>'required',
            'file' => 'required',                
        ]);

        $DocumentType->name = $request->input('name');
        $fileName = time().'.'.$request->file->extension();  
        $request->file->move(public_path('Files'), $fileName);
        $DocumentType->file =  $name;
         $DocumentType->save();
         return response()->json($DocumentType);

  }
```

**Vue code is**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
 <div
      class="modal fade"
      id="addNew"
      tabindex="-1"
      role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="addNewLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" v-show="!editMode" id="addNewLabel">ثبت اسناد جدید</h5>
            <h5 class="modal-title" v-show="editMode" id="addNewLabel">تمدید اسناد</h5>

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 317px;">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <form
            @submit.prevent="editMode ? updateDocumentType() : createDocumentType()"
            enctype="multipart/form-data"
          >
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  v-model="form.name"
                  placeholder="نام"
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  class="form-control"
                  :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('name') }"
                />
                <has-error :form="form" field="name"></has-error>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="file" class="col-sm-4 control-label">File</label>

                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    class="form-input"
                    :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('file') }"
                    id="file"
                    name="file"
                  />
                  <has-error :form="form" field="file"></has-error>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">لغو</button>

                <button
                  v-show="editMode"
                  :disabled="form.busy"
                  type="submit"
                  class="btn btn-success"
                >تمدید</button>
                <button
                  v-show="!editMode"
                  :disabled="form.busy"
                  type="submit"
                  class="btn btn-primary"
                >ثبت</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
  </div>
<script>
  createDocumentType() {
      // axios.get("api/getAllDocumentTypeDocumentType").then(response => {
      //   let data = response.data;

      if (this.form.name == "") {
        toast.fire({
          type: "warning",
          icon: "warning",
          html: "<h5>نام لازم است.</h5>"
        });
      }
      // else if (this.form.file == "") {
      //   toast.fire({
      //     type: "warning",
      //     icon: "warning",
      //     html: "<h5>لطفا،اسناد را انتخاب نماید.</h5>"
      //   });
      // }
      else {
        this.form
          .post("api/DocumentType")
          .then(() => {
            //    the below function will be use to reload the page

            //   this.$emit("refreshPage");
            $("#addNew").modal("hide");
            toast.fire({
              icon: "success",
              type: "success",
              html: "<h5> اسنادموافقانه اجاد گردید</h5>"
            });
            Fire.$emit("refreshPage");
            this.form.reset();
            //   this.$Progress.finish();
          })
          .catch(er => {
            console.log(er);
          });
      }
    }
</script>
```

> Migration table code

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('document_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
             $table->string('name');            
            $table->string('file')->nullable();
             $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Code in API route**

```
Route::apiResources(['DocumentType'=>'API\DocumentTypeController']);
Route::get('getAllDocumentType','API\DocumentTypeController@getAll');
```

Answer (score 0):

The given data was invalid.","errors":{"file":["The file field is required. This error is because there is no existing file in your payload upon submission of your form.

in your form, bind data to your input file like what you did to your input name. like this

```
<input
      type="file"
      v-model="form.file"
      class="form-input"
      :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('file') }"
       id="file"
      name="file"
 />
```

Or, attach an event to this file input and process the file provided. like this

```
<input
          type="file"
          class="form-input"
          :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('file') }"
          id="file"
          name="file"
          @change="selectFile"
/>
```

Then in your methods, create also a selectFile function

```
methods: {
    selectFile(file) {
         if(file == "") return false

         this.form.file = file.target.files
         console.log(this.form.file)
    }
}
```

Comment: it give me this error  [vue/valid-v-model]
'v-model' directives don't support 'file' input type.eslint-plugin-vue

Comment: give me this error "message": "Call to a member function extension() on array",

Comment: what you did so far ?

Comment: did you remove the v-model in your input file ?

Comment: did you remove the v-model in your input file ?

Comment: did you try to console log the file in your selectFile function ?

Comment: yes I did and give me "message": "Call to a member function extension() on array", in the console

Comment: remove first the this.form.file = file.target.files, just console the file if what is inside of it.

Comment: give this error {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"file":["The file field is required."]}}

Comment: no i mean, the moment you select file you will trigger the selectFile function right ? show the console log of it if what is inside.

Comment: console.log(file) ? nothing ? Are you sure ?

Comment: no, not console.log(this.form.file) but console.log(file)

Comment: nothing is in the console, no error, dose not show any file

Comment: console.log(file) not console.log(this.form.file)

Comment: nothing is in the selectFile(file) {
      console.log(file);
    },